# php echo showing question marks instead of arabic letters

Tags: php, arabic

I use PHP (echo) to add user session data to the HTML page and it worked fine on one server but when I moved to another one it shows Arabic data in question marks like this (???). how to fix this?

NOTE 1: Arabic data added in the html page using HTML or JAVASCRIPT or AJAX call from database is showing correctly. it only shows question marks when using PHP echo command.

update: the first duplicate is about setting up a server but I'm using a shared webhosting. the second one is about sending email and changing the header didn't work for me.

UPDATE: looks like it was a problem while restoring the database to the new server. new entered data is showing correctly while old ones are messed up!

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze I did all the above but it's still not working. could you please point to a specific part of the article?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to help you.